# Problemas ao efetuar login com Vue, Vuex, axios e Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, session, login, vuex

Estou tentando fazero login em uma aplicação que utiliza o laravel como back/api e o front com vue/vuex/vue-router, porém ao receber o token eu não consigo manter o estado na store após atualizar a página, o estado só continua com o usuário se eu trocar de página via **router-link**.
O componente Login.vue está assim:

```js
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return() {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            }

        }
    },
    computed: {
        stateUser() {
            return this.$store.state.user
        },
        getUser() {
            return this.$store.getters.getUser
        }
    },

    created() {
        console.log("USUARIO ", this.getUser)
    },

    methods: {
        doLogin(){
            axios.post('/api/login', this.form)
            .then(response => {

                 // efetua o login caso a api retorne o token
                if (response.data.token) {

                    sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))

                    this.$store.commit('SET_USER')
                    console.log(this.getUser)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            });
        }

}
<script>
```

Todo esse processo está funcionando, ao verificar as sessões ativas no navegador  ela está lá criada normalmente

O problema ocorre quando atualizo a página, nesse momento a minha **state.user** volta a ser false, ela acaba perdendo os dados do estado.. segue a minha store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)


const state = { 
    user: false,
}

const mutations = {

    SET_USER (state) {

        const userSession = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));

        if (userSession) {
            state.user = {
                id: userSession.id,
                name: userSession.name,
                email: userSession.email,
                token: userSession.token,
            }
        }
    },


    UNSET_USER(state) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        state.user = false;
    }

}


const getters = {
    getUser(state) {
        return state.user;
    }
}


export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
})
```

Estou utilizando o passport do laravel e está retornando o token normalmente. O problema está mesmo no momento em que acesso outra página via url ou atualizo a página fazendo com que a state não mantenha os dados

Se alguém puder indicar algum tutorial ou referência para esse problema

Muito obrigado

Comment: Você tem que salvar os dados referente ao login em algum lugar (Cookie, Web Storange, Local Storange, etc) pois quando o usuário atualiza a pagina ele "limpa" o estado, as informações que estão no vuex. Geralmente a lógica é algo como, efetua login, salva os dados em algum lugar que possa recuperar depois, salva no vuex. Ocorreu um refresh recupera os dados de login salvos, se estiver ok segue, se não estiver redireciona para a tela de login.

Comment: Eu estou salvando ele na sessionStorage e pegando na mutation SET_USER mas ainda não é mantido

Answer (score 1):

voce esta usando o getItem, ele é para captar os dados e nao gravar.. tente  `sessionStorage.setItem('chave', 'valor');`

coloque a `chave` como 'user' e no valor vc coloca o objeto com os dados do usuario :D